# How to trigger a jQuery on ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question about jQuery..

I have an ajax function to make click event after success:

```
      var rowdiv = '#DiamondSetting';
        $(rowdiv).hide();
        $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: TabURL,
            data: "",

            beforeSend: function () {
                $(rowdiv).html('<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"><tr><td align="center"><img src="../Content/images/loading_row.gif" alt="updating" /><td></tr></table>');
            }, //show loading just when link is clicked 
            complete: function () {
                //$(updatediv).html("rejected");
            }, //stop showing loading when the process is complete 
            success: function (html) { //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html 
                //$(updatediv).html(html); //show the html inside .content div
                $(rowdiv).hide();
                $(rowdiv).fadeIn("slow");
                $(rowdiv).html(html);
                //select a particular metal after post back 
                $('input[id=metal0]').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
                $("#metal0").attr("disabled", true);

                $("#Romantic").bind('click');
            }
        });
```

As you can see, after success:

What I want is when I click a link inside a li with id="Romantic", a checkbox with id="metal0" will checked and disabled..

But, it didn't trigger the id="Romantic"..

Everytime I go to the page, the checkbox with id="metal0" will checked and disabled..

So when I reload the page, the jQuery still trigger on it..

How can I trigger the jQuery and remove it after I reload the page?

Thank You Guys.. ;)

Comment: `How can I trigger the jQuery` what does this mean ?

Answer (score 2):

**ID on a page is unique..**

So this  `$('input[id=metal0]')` can be written as `$('#metal0')`

Next setting the `disabled` property does not mean that the event will not be fired.. You are looking for the `off` method

```
$("#metal0").off("click"); // This will unbind the event handler
                           // if you attached the event using on
```

This line makes no sense

```
$("#Romantic").bind('click');
```

You seem to be binding the event but there is no click handler associated to it.